# Android : how to maintain session on back button?

Tags: android

My App contains two Activity Classes. from first activity user can login and from second activity user can view their project details.I'm maintaining session also with logout button. In my app if user clicked on back button from second activity then it goes to apps section(means main menu) and after some time user clicked on my app icon it goes to first activity not second activity yet user didn't logout. 
`I want user should go to second activity not first activity if user already login`. I had tried but 
not working and still I am trying. 
How can i do the above stuff please anybody suggest me the answer.

Comment: then it goes to home means main app....... what do you mean by that? exiting the app?

Answer (score 0):

You should save the state of current user in to [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

In the **onCreate** method of your logIn Activity, before you call **setContentView()**, you can check if the user is logged in. If this is *true* open new Activity wish **startActivity()** and call **finish()** on current Activity. If not just continue with the normal **setContentView()** call.

This way the logIn activity will not be visible if she state inside SharedPreferences is set to logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to display first activity. But in fact there is always main activity. That should decide whether to start directly login activity, or to display user content directly.
You can use finish() from main activity as soon as you started login or content activity, so when user pushes back(), he will not see main activity again.

```
MainActivity extends Activity
{
 public void onCreate()
 {
   if isLogged()
     startActivity(new Intent(ContentActivity ...));
   else
     startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity...));
   finish()
}

LoginActivity extends Activity
{
  ...
  public void onLoginSuccess(String username)
  {
     // called from dialog OK button and login process success
     startActivity(new Intent(ContentActivity ...));
     finish();
  }
}
```

Comment: good solution for me but why you write onLoginSuccess? I think MainActivity is sufficent for check user login details. I just wrote if isLogged()  startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity ...)) is it fine?