# Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46029dd0 that was originally added here

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am getting this error : has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46029dd0 that was originally added here
I have net connection in emulator, check it out browser by opening websites.

I am getting error at the line of processdialog.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Register.this, "",
                "Registering... Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        name = new PropertyInfo();
        name.setName("Name");
        name.setValue(Name);
        name.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(name);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envp.dotNet = true;
        envp.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envp.getResponse();
            Response = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            textValidation.setText(e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: activity has leaked window due to progress dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165810/android-activity-has-leaked-window-due-to-progress-dialog)

Comment: please change `Void` to `void`

Comment: probably App is crashing be because you are trying to update UI element from `doInBackground` so use `onPostExecute` for updating ui elements instead of  doInBackground

Comment: yeah, rite.. it was showing bcz of UI element from doInBackground... thank you so much.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This error will happen if your activity has been destroyed but you dialog is still showing.
So You have added these code in your activity's `onDestroy()`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: App was crashing i was trying to update UI element from doInBackground.

Comment: U cannot change UI from another background thread. Try changing from postExecute

Comment: rite, vivek. But then why it is working when I am not sending data to my computer local server. I have changed it to main server of my company and that time only, I got this error.

Comment: `super.onDestroy()` should be called first.

Comment: Thank Johan S, I confirm that you are right :). I have misunderstood it for a very long time.

Comment: LOL i am impressed you know why .. I didt declare dialog and when I i hve used this on destroy .. my issue got fixed lol :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Possibly Its Because of you are writing**

```
textValidation.setText(e.toString());
```

**inside the function,**

```
doInBackground()
```

**which is updating UI which is allowed by android in doInBackground() method. So somehow if you put this line in**

postExecute()

**then this problem will get resolved.**