# Creating a dialog in the onCreate method - Leak

Tags: android, dialog, splash-screen, oncreate, resource-leak

I'm seem to intermittently be getting the following error when I'm running my app.

"Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40521348 that was originally added here"

All I'm doing is creating my dialog in my onCreate() method like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//Create splash-screen object and pass in width and height (width and height are defined and valid, I just removed them from this post to make it more readable)

    splash = new SplashScreen(MainActivity.this, width, height);

//Create dialog that will show splash-screen 
    loading_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

//Set and display splash screen view
    loading_dialog.setContentView(splash);
    loading_dialog.show();
}
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

You can create dialog in onCreate but you can't show it, because activity is not visible yet. Google it, there was an example how to do it right somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I belive you need to create your dialog before showing it.

you need to do :

```
loading_dialog.create().show();
```

instead

```
loading_dialog.show();
```

I find Similar Q, you can use them

[Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f72ff0 that was originally added here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957409/activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindowdecorvie)

[Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

[Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46029dd0 that was originally added here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768721/activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindowdecorvie)

Comment: Hey @idan, thanks but that doesn't work - there is no 'create()' method....  what I'm doing does work, the error is only intermittent! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you don't cancel() your dialog before closing Activity.
Try to do cancel() on your dialog in onStop() method. It should help.
Hope it helps.