# Android : Window Manager : android view window leaked

Tags: android

Right after I fix my first problem this one comes up :( please help me fix it..

> 03-02 12:47:02.785    9439-9439/com.ucu.ccs.classrecord
>   E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.ucu.ccs.classrecord.Login has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{6d17cc4
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-1002,348} that was originally added here
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:465)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:277)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>               at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:312)
>               at com.ucu.ccs.classrecord.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:158)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
>               at com.ucu.ccs.classrecord.Login.isOnline(Login.java:113)
>               at com.ucu.ccs.classrecord.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:73)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

here is my code:

```
buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String instructor_id = editUser.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = editPass.getText().toString().trim();

                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
                preferences.edit().putString("password", password).commit();
                preferences.edit().putString("inst_id", instructor_id).commit();

                if (editUser.getText().toString().equals("") || editPass.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Instructor ID and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    isOnline();
                }

            }
        });

public boolean isOnline(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        }else {
            checkInternet();
        }
        return false;
    }

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        boolean failure = false;
        String inst_id = editUser.getText().toString();
        String password = editPass.getText().toString();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            int success;
            try{
                List<NameValuePair> mList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                mList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("instructor_id", inst_id));
                mList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", mList);
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //finish();
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }

            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            session.setLogin(true);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (s != null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you did? i mean what you did after clicking on button?

Comment: I just click the button then progress dialog comes up after it finished processing the app crash

Comment: [Take a look at this it seems that your Dialog is still showing.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768721/activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindowdecorvie/16768747#16768747)

Comment: Why are you concerned about this warning?  Did it make your app crash

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.
In your **doInBackground** when you are shifting your activity dismiss the dialog before  **startActivity(i)**
try this and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your activity is getting finished some how, so you need to close dialog.

In onPause() add below code

```
if(isFinishing()){
    if (pDialog!= null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog= null;
    }
}
```