# Does android windowLeak lead to memory leak ？

Tags: android, memory-leaks, window

when finish a activity with a showing dialog , warning will show as bellow , does this result to memory leak , or just warning

```
      WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity  MainActivity 
      has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{a310978 V.ED..... R......D 0,0-1080,1704} 
      that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
    at com.snail.labaffinity.activity.FullScrreenDialog.show(FullScrreenDialog.java:81)
    at com.snail.labaffinity.activity.MainActivity.alertdialog(MainActivity.java:71)
    at com.snail.labaffinity.activity.MainActivity$$ViewBinder$4.doClick(MainActivity$$ViewBinder.java:47)
    at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a memory leak sometimes it tends to crash your application. 
This error will happen if your activity has been destroyed. This error will occur when you're using dialog..! so handle your dialog finished.

@Override

```
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
if (dialog != null) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog = null;
}
```

}
as my reference [Android : Window Manager : android view window leaked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738795/android-window-manager-android-view-window-leaked)

Comment: thanks , i know this  .  however,  i wonder if windowleak leads to memory leak

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your are not dismissing the dialog that you have already created and you are directly closing your activity.

This error seems small but some times it leads to a crash.

So kindly dismiss your dialog before finishing activity , as suggested by @hemanth reddy

Comment: Does windowLeak lead to memory leak ？