# Android app works for 1 type of value of Json but not another

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building an android application, and whenever I send a get request to my server it returns Jsons like:

```
{
    "status":"error",
    "error":"Username already exists."
}
```

or when the user doesn't exists and so does the email:

```
{
    "status":"ok",
    "cookie":"test16|1519060288|Jf8jEzJe8C7JJWmAxW6ViJbLKgsY1XuCH0OStT38vG2|d6489d623438870a08da717cc6f1851496c2e1e7c45557da7c8df8d1f80f1db4",
    "user_id":285
}
```

The thing is, for the second Json, everything works Perfectly, the user gets an email, the app does as it should.
But when you try to register with an existing username, eveything crashes,
and from my logcat, I found that it crashes in the line of BufferReader declaration, or in this line : `if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)`, if I choose to include it.
What reason on earth could be that my code accepts one type of Jsons where `"status" = "ok"`, and not when it equals "error"?

this is my asynctask:

```
    public class Register extends AsyncTask<String, Void, RegisterData> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        p= ProgressDialog.show(SignUpActivity.this,getString(R.string.Authenticating),getString(R.string.loadingPleaseWait),true);
        p.setCancelable(true);
        p.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        p.setMessage(getString(R.string.loadingDotDotDot));
        p.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected RegisterData doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String str=params[0];
        String res=performPostCall(str);
        Log.d("ress", res);
        if (Response.matches(""))
        {
            register.cancel(true);
        }
        RegisterData regi = null;
        try
        {

            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(res);
            String Status = json_data.getString("status");
            String error = "null";
            if (Status.equals("ok"))
                error = "null";
            else
                error= json_data.getString("error");
            Log.d("coo", error);
            regi= new RegisterData(Status,error);
            Log.d("stat", regi.getStatus());
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {

        }
        Log.d("aa", res);
        return regi;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(RegisterData result) {
        Log.d("stat2", result.getStatus());

        if (result.getStatus().equals("ok")) {
            check = true;
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, R.string.SuccessfulLogin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, R.string.WrongUserOrPass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        p.dismiss();

    }
}
```

this is the class that performs the http request:

```
    public String performPostCall(String requestURL) {

    URL url;
    Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 1");
    String response = "";
    try {
        String str=getPostDataString();
        Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 2");

        url = new URL(requestURL+str);
        Log.d("nugi", url.toString());

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 3");
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"));
        Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 4");
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
                Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 5");
            }
        Log.d("nugi", response);

        Response = response;
        }
        /*else {
            response="";
            Response = response;

        }*/
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

this is my logcat error:

> 02-05 17:24:28.075 5378-5394/com.example.negev.peulibraryv201 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab38aea0
>   02-05 17:24:28.082 5378-5394/com.example.negev.peulibraryv201 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab38a5e0
>   02-05 17:24:28.332 5378-5378/com.example.negev.peulibraryv201 E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.negev.peulibraryv201.SignUpActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{bd0880e V.E...... R......D 0,0-729,322} that was originally added here
>                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
>                                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
>                                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
>                                                                                      at com.example.negev.peulibraryv201.SignUpActivity$Register.onPreExecute(SignUpActivity.java:156)
>                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
>                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
>                                                                                      at com.example.negev.peulibraryv201.SignUpActivity.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:87)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Thank you!

Comment: The  problem is not the Json but your Dialog. When you've an error you try to dismiss it

Comment: What do you mean? where? and there shouldn't be any errors the Json should always be written in the BufferReader no? and thank!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850597/1827254

Comment: You error is `E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.negev.peulibraryv201.SignUpActivity has leaked window `

Comment: can you check what is the `responseCode (int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode())` when you get an error from API? is it 200?

Comment: also I suspect that this is the actual error. Scroll up in Android Logcat window & see if you see another error.

Comment: @SandipSoni There is no error from the API. The logs refers to a `Windowleaked` issue, which means OP tries to dismiss a Dialog when the Activity View has been destroyed

Comment: @Eselfar This also happens when your app crashes before reaching to the dismiss line. So what might happening here is, app is getting crashed due to some other problem, may be a `NullPointer` & the window gets leaked. That's why I asked OP to check the responseCode in case of error & the logs for other error

Comment: Oh, the value of int responseCode is 404, what on earth could be the reason if I manage to put the same address and get a json?

Comment: @NegNeg64 comment the if responseCode condition. Your code is not going inside that condition because HTTP_OK code is 200 & your API returns 404 in case of error

Comment: the thing is, even when I remove this line, the bufferreader is unable to build the Json...

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165810/android-activity-has-leaked-window-due-to-progress-dialog) answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem lies somewhere else as per our talk in comment. Your API returns status 404 when it returns error while your app only checks for status code 200 (HTTP_OK). You'll need to handle few stuff here, I haven't tested it, but you can try the following in `performPostCall`:

```
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 3");
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"));
            Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 4");
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
                Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 5");
            }
            Log.d("nugi", response);

            Response = response;
        } else {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream(), "iso-8859-1"));
            Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 4");
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
                Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 5");
            }
            Log.d("nugi", response);

            Response = response;
        }
```

Notice the `conn.getErrorStream()` in else condition. You might need to play with it as I don't remember exactly. The thing now is, you won't get the data in `inputStream` when the status is not 200

Comment: Thanks a lot, that indeed was the issue!

Comment: and by the way, your solution is far better than mine, I didn't know you can do that! I'll delete mine, yours work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably leaked window. You are calling `finish`, just **before** dismissing the progress, when the status is **OK**.

```
    if (result.getStatus().equals("ok")) {
        check = true;
        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, R.string.SuccessfulLogin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish(); // <<<< finish() is called before dismissing the progress
    }
    else
    {
        check = false;
        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, R.string.WrongUserOrPass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    p.dismiss();
```

You can do this:

```
    if (result.getStatus().equals("ok")) {
        check = true;
        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, R.string.SuccessfulLogin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        p.dismiss(); // <<<< call dismiss first 
        finish(); // <<<< then call finish()
    }
    else
    {
        check = false;
        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, R.string.WrongUserOrPass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        p.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: The thing is the project fails when the status is not "ok", what could it be you think? when the status is "ok" things work perfectly... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

`d.dismiss();`

by

```
if (d.isShowing()){
   d.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys with the help of Sandip Soni I managed to solve the issue, or more accurately he did, so the credit is his.
the problem was that my api gave 404 in its response code integer, and didn't let me read the Json for some reason.
the solution was to add an "if" statement here:

```
     int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 3");
        String line;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"));
    Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 4");
    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            response+=line;
            Log.d("nugi", "Got Here 5");
        }
    Log.d("nugi", response);

    Response = response;
    }
    else { <<<<<<<<<<< //if statement here
        response="";
        Response = response;

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return response;
```

}

then to check if it's empty and activate a toast that says "Username or Email are already in use".
Thank a lot guys! this is such an amazing forum.